# Angular-Material "md-datepicker" directive - "md-open-on-focus" issue

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

As exampled in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/goueo40n/2/), there's seems to be an inconsistency issue with opening the `md-datepicker` multiple times when using `md-open-on-focus`.

The problem occurs after opening and closing it for the first time (which works ok) - after that, it'll randomly open on click and become unstable.

```
<md-datepicker ng-model="timeModel" md-hide-icons="all" md-open-on-focus></md-datepicker>
```

Has anyone experienced the same behavior and found a solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, the problem with **`md-hide-icons="all"`** and **`md-open-on-focus`** used together is, **when you click outside, the focus remains on the input**. But, since there are no icons to click for and focus is already on the input, there is no way we can open the datepicker.

If you click outside, **and click outside again**, focus from the input is gone, and it will work normally from there on *which should arguably be the expected behavior*.

But if you don't want such behavior, we can do something to change it!

Now, having a look at the `datePicker` code, in the `closeCalendarPane` function, they have

```
self.calendarPaneOpenedFrom.focus();
```

which is responsible for keeping focus on input. If we remove it, it would lose focus while clicking outside (or selecting a date from the picker) which is exactly what we want. They have some code handling input when `openOnFocus` is true but not sure how that helps!

[**Forked jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/6q4qprkf/) (changed line is at #31449)

Also, changing the library code isn't what we would normally want to do. So, for now, you could have a workaround like having a callback on `md-is-open` and removing the focus from the input element inside callback using your favourite way (`jQuery`/`angular.element` or pure JS) [As mentioned by @quirimmo]

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this functionality it's not implemented yet in angular material.
If you take a look to the official examples, you will see the same behavior in the one using md-open-on-focus.
https://material.angularjs.org/1.1.0/demo/datepicker

You need a little workaround in order to make it works. Just changed your example code:

HTML:

```
<md-datepicker ng-model="timeModel" md-hide-icons="all" md-is-open="isOpen" md-open-on-focus></md-datepicker>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('sandbox', ['ngMaterial'])
.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.timeModel = new Date();
  $scope.$watch('isOpen', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    if (!newValue && oldValue) {
        document.querySelector('.md-datepicker-input').blur();
    }  
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ecs9ao89/

You can achieve also the same behavior defining a new directive and requiring the base datepicker of angular material, and open it on click.
But this solution is smaller effort.